# Prove that if $A^{2}=A$ and $A=A^{T}$, then $A$ is a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I am trying to complete this proof but am confused on where to start. The book gives the hint that I should first decide onto which subspace it should be projecting. So should I be assuming that A is a projection matrix and then verifying that $A^{2}=A$ and $A=A^{T}$? It then goes on to give another hint that says to show that for all **x**, the vector $A\textbf{x}$ lies in the subspace and $\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}$ is orthogonal to that subspace.

Comment: What is your definition of a projection matrix?

Comment: $A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$

Comment: You definitely don't want to assume that A is a projection matrix if the task is to prove that A is a projection matrix. You must work from your premises to your conclusion.

Comment: @RNG that's what I thought. But I'm not sure how just $A^{2}=A$ and $A=A^{T}$ will help me conclude A is a projection matrix. Or how the hints relate to be useful.

Comment: Which book are you using, and what is the full statement of the definition of a projection matrix?

Comment: @user84413 the book is called "Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach" by Shifrin and Adams. It says "for projection onto a subspace $V\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ we have $\textbf{p}=\text{proj}_{V}\textbf{b}=(A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T})\textbf{b}$ for every vector $\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, it follows that the matrix $P_{V}=A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$ is the appropriate 'projection matrix'"

Comment: Thanks for sending this information.

Comment: @carmichael561 what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let V be the column space of A, so $Ax\in V$ for all x.

Since $A^{T}=A$, V is also the row space of A.

Since $A(x-Ax)=Ax-A^{2}x=Ax-Ax=0$ for all x,  $x-Ax$ is in the 
nullspace of $A$ for every x.

Then
$x-Ax$ is orthogonal to $Ax$ for every $x$

since the row space and null space of A are orthogonal subspaces;

so $A$ is the projection matrix onto its column space.